# Find out if .png file is a screenshot?

Tags: macos, screenshot, nsfilemanager

When I get the attributes of a specific file with the following code:

```
NSFileManager *fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
NSDictionary *attributes = [fileManager attributesOfItemAtPath:p error:nil];
```

Is there an attribute to know if it's a screenshot or not?

Right now I'm using this awkward piece of code:

```
if ([fileExtension isEqualToString:@"png"]) {
  NSMutableArray *separatetFilename;
  separatetFilename = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:[fileName componentsSeparatedByString:@" "]]; /* screenshots have multiple spaces in their names, I split them up to use the information */

  if ([separatetFilename count] == 4) { /* screenshots names have 4 parts when splittet by spaces */
    if ([[separatetFilename objectAtIndex:0] isEqualToString:@"Bildschirmfoto"]) { /* Bildschirmfoto = Screenshot in German */
      /* Do Something */
    }
  }
}
```

With this solution I would have to put in localized Strings for the "Screenshot" string... I searched the documentary but didn't find anything. Is there a "isScreenshot" flag or something I could read?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question "Is there a "isScreenshot" flag or something I could read?" and the answer is "YES".

I know of two ways to get the answer:

a) ask the NSFile~Manager

b) ask for metadata.

You already used:

```
NSFileManager *fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
NSDictionary *attributes = [fileManager attributesOfItemAtPath:p error:nil];
```

If you now have a look at the keys of this dictionary e.g. with

```
NSLog( @"the keys: %@", [attributes allKeys] );
```

you will find the key @"NSFileExtendedAttributes*". The value of this key is a dictionary with keys like *com.apple.metadata:kMDItemIsScreenCapture* or *com.apple.metadata:kMDItemScreenCaptureType* or .... This is what you asked for. The corresponding values are NSData-objects with a binary property list. Evaluating these plist give something like **1** (it is a screenshot) and **window** for a window screenshot or **selection** for  a part of the window.

Looking at the metadata can be done with:

```
    MDItemRef item = MDItemCreate( kCFAllocatorDefault, (CFStringRef)p );
```

If you only need the above mentioned values create a list (an NSArray) with the corresponding keys:

```
NSArray *ary = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:
     @"kMDItemIsScreenCapture", @"kMDItemScreenCaptureType", nil];
NSDictionary *dict =
    (NSDictionary *)MDItemCopyAttributes( item, (CFArrayRef)ary );
```

and test what it returns;

```
NSLog( @"the metadata are %@", dict );
```

In this case the returned values are __NSCFBoolean (i.e. NSNumber) and __NSCFString (i.e. NSString) which is a bit simpler to work with than a binary plist.

Comment: Thank you very, very much! I thought I had seen this attribute while debugging, but couldn't find it again. Much appreciatet!